# How to disable signaturePad (canvas) after ajax success

Tags: jquery, canvas, html5-canvas, signaturepad

I am using this [plugin](https://github.com/thomasjbradley/signature-pad/blob/gh-pages/documentation.md).

My application submits signature with ajax call. On a succesful ajax return I want to disable any signature changes by user. The last thing I tried is a following, but the signature pad is still active and drawing lines (listeners afe not detached):

```
   function showResponse(itemJson, statusText, xhr, $form) {

    if (itemJson.status == 'success') {

        debugger;

        $($form.find('.clearButton')).remove();
        $($form.find('button')).remove();

        $form.find('input').attr('readonly', 'readonly');

        var api = $form.signaturePad();
        var sig = api.getSignatureString();

        api.updateOptions({displayOnly: true})
//        $form.signaturePad({displayOnly: true}).regenerate(sig);

    }
}
```

Does anyone know how to update existing signaturePad, so it turns into disabled mode ?

Comment: The following change of option works: $sigPadElem.signaturePad({ penColour: '#FF0000' }).regenerate($sigPadElem.find('.output').val());

Comment: Do you mind sharing what solution you ended up using? Thanks.

Comment: I ended up removing the signature pad recently. But before that, I used approach to check if the signature exists then load inactive pad with signature. There should be an example how to show existing signatures.

Answer (score 6):

Usually i use:

```
api.off();
```

It works in my software

Answer (score 2):

For anyone finding this thread while using the React package react-signature-canvas; you can disable it by calling `padRef.current.off().`

Here's a basic example of a pad that displays a given signature (sigValue) and is disabled

```
const SignatureDisplay = ({ sigValue }) => {
  const padRef = useRef({})

  useEffect(() => {
    padRef.current.fromData(sigValue || [])
    padRef.current.off()
  }, [])

  return (
    <SignaturePad
      ref={padRef}
      canvasProps={{
        height: 200,
        width: 400
      }}/>
  )
}
```

Comment: A little out of topic, but how did you get the padRef.current available in the useEffect? Mine always throws undefined when trying to call fromData

Comment: @LuanScudeler bit of a cheat but if you pass an argument to useRef that will be the initial value, in the above code I have set it to an empty object which stops it from blowing up in the useEffect. Alternatively you could just add a guard clause to the useEffect eg `if(!padRef.current) { return }`. 

Sorry for not getting back sooner, hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Added to jquery.signaturepad.js:

```js
  $.extend(self, {
    /**
     * A property to store the current version of Signature Pad
     */
    signaturePad : '{{version}}'
...
    , disableCanvas : function () { disableCanvas() }    

    , clearAndDraw : function () { drawIt() }
...
```

To use it:

```
$sigPadElem.signaturePad().disableCanvas();
```

or:

```
$sigPadElem.signaturePad().clearAndDraw();
```

I wonder if this functionality can be done without modifying the plugin? (BTW I am unable to give the bounty to myself...)

Answer (score -2):

Try this

```
$('.sigPad').signaturePad('disable');
```